# Multiple where clause in YII2

Tags: closures, yii2

I have a Question, How to use Closure type Active records Query in YII2 with conditional WHERE.

Here what i want to achive:

```
public function getUsers($limit = 10, $type = 1, $company_id = 0) { 
    return User::find()->where( function($query) use ($type, $company_id){       
                $query->where(['type' => $type]); 
                if($company_id != 0) { 
                   $query->andWhere(['company_id' => $company_id]); 
                } 
               })
            ->orderBy([ 'created_at'=> SORT_DESC, ]) 
            ->limit($limit); 
}
```

Please Help if someone know about this.1

Answer (score 5):

Can't figure out what for Closure here.
You can use `andFilterWhere()` for `company_id` condition, but you should set it to null as default, so this condition will be ignored if company_id wasn't initialized:

```
public function getUsers($limit = 10, $type = 1, $company_id = null) { 
    return User::find()
            ->where(['type' => $type])
            ->andFilterWhere(['company_id' => $company_id])
            ->orderBy([ 'created_at'=> SORT_DESC ]) 
            ->limit($limit)
            ->all(); //probably you muiss it
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#andFilterWhere()-detail

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getUsers($limit = 10, $type = 1, $company_id = null) 
{
       $query =User::find()
            ->where(['type' => $type])
            ->orderBy([ 'created_at'=> SORT_DESC ]) 
            ->limit($limit)
            ->all(); 

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

      // then filter data
      if($company_id != null)
          $query->andFilterWhere(['company_id' => $company_id]);
}
```

Comment: When using `andFilterWhere`, check for `null` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Laravel MVC and something like that was ok for me.

Replace

```
$query->andWhere(['company_id' => $company_id]);
```

with

```
$query->where(['company_id' => $company_id]);
```